# How to write comments after self defined environment header

Tags: environments

I have defined an environment viz.`Examples` in the following way:

```
\newtheoremstyle{myexcstyle}{3ex}{3ex}{}{}{\scshape}{:}{.5em}{}
\theoremstyle{myexcstyle}
\newtheorem*{exmps}{Examples}
\newenvironment{Exmps}
{
    \begin{exmps}\
        \vspace{-1ex}
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}., itemsep=1.5ex]
        }
        {
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{exmps}
}
```

Now, at some point of my text, I started with a few examples after a defintion, then some theorems, and then I want to continue with the examples. In the second appearance of the `Examples` I want to make it look like "Examples (continued):". Precisely what  am asking for is:

> Definition:
>
> Examples:
>
> 1.
>
> 2.
>
> Theorem:
>
> Examples (continued):
>
> 3.
>
> 4.

How do I achieve this?

**Edit:** An MWE:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\newtheoremstyle{myexcstyle}{3ex}{3ex}{}{}{\scshape}{:}{.5em}{}
\theoremstyle{myexcstyle}
\newtheorem*{exmps}{Examples}
\newenvironment{Exmps}
{
    \begin{exmps}\
        \vspace{-1ex}
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}., itemsep=1.5ex]
        }
        {
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{exmps}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{Exmps}[continued]
        \item Example 3
    \end{Exmps}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the optional argument of the environment: `\begin{exmps}[continued]....\end[exmps}`.

Comment: It worked with the `exmps` but not with `Exmps`. There I needed to write the entire definition of `Exmps` using `exmps`.

Comment: Please post a complete code that we can compile. You do not even say which package you load  for theorems formatting.

Comment: @Bernard Posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are. I slightly modified your code: needless to load  `amsfonts` when you load `amssymb` , and `amsmath` when you load `mathtools`. Other problem: `\textbf` shouldn't be used with `label=`, because any reference to an item of of the list will be bolded and this is usually unwanted. It is better to set it via the key `font=\bfseries`.

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\newtheoremstyle{myexcstyle}{3ex}{3ex}{}{}{\scshape}{:}{.5em}{}
\theoremstyle{myexcstyle}
\newtheorem*{exmps}{Examples}
\newenvironment{Exmps}[1][]
{%
        \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}
    {\begin{exmps}}{\begin{exmps}[#1]}
        \leavevmode\vspace{-1ex}
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*., font=\bfseries, itemsep=1.5ex]
        }
        {
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{exmps}
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{Exmps}[continued]
        \item
        Example 3
    \end{Exmps}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. Last year I just took to type a lecture note of my Professor to learn TeX without any prior knowledge of it. It is this site that has helped me throughout the entire journey. Coming to the question, your code is not working without the comment, i.e., although `begin{Exmps}[continued]...\end{Exmps}` is working, but `\begin{Exmps}...\end{Exmps}` is giving the error "Undefined control sequence. \item". How to handle this?

Comment: @SubhajitPaul/ I should have tested this case, sorry. I've added  the package `xifthen`  to check whether the optional arguments is given or not, with the`\isempty` command.

Comment: Thanks. Worked like charm. I have another small query regarding this. Is there an easy way to resume the `enumerate list` in the `[continue]` section? Or does this query deserve a separate question?

Comment: Maybe  you should add another (mandatory) argument to the environment, to define a  `series=` key. This way you might have several groups of environments with independent numbering.